# Message sent to deallocated instance -- short and simple

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

This has to be very basic, but I don't see the problem. The program crashes whenever the following code block is executed. Analyzer reports a possible memory leak:

```
if (anImage) {
    eventImageView.frame = defaultEventImageFrame;
    UIImage *scaledImage = [anImage scaleToFitWithin:defaultEventImageFrame.size interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
    eventImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:scaledImage];                
}
```

The message is  -[UIImage release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1129d920*

Instance 0x1129d920 is scaledImage

I tried adding retains and releases, like this

```
if (anImage) {
    eventImageView.frame = defaultEventImageFrame;
    UIImage *scaledImage = [[anImage scaleToFitWithin:defaultEventImageFrame.size interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh] retain];
    eventImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:scaledImage];                
    [scaledImage release];        
}
```

and still get the error message.

So I tried replacing the assignment with a copy, like this

```
if (anImage) {
    eventImageView.frame = defaultEventImageFrame;
    UIImage *scaledImage = [anImage copy];
    eventImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:scaledImage];                
}
```

And the problem is gone.

Checking the scaleToFitWithin method, I see it returns an autoreleased object:

```
- (UIImage *) scaleToFitWithin:(CGSize) newSize
          interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality{

    CGSize originalImageSize = self.size;
    CGSize newImageSize;
    if (originalImageSize.width <= originalImageSize.height) {
        newImageSize.width = self.size.width * newSize.width  / self.size.width;
        newImageSize.height = self.size.height * newSize.width  / self.size.width;
    }
    else {
        newImageSize.width = self.size.width * newSize.height  / self.size.height;
        newImageSize.height = self.size.height * newSize.height  / self.size.height;        
    }
    return [[[self normalize] resizedImage:newImageSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh] autorelease];

}
```

So there is something about memory management that I'm not understanding. What is the problem likely to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the `scaleToFitWithin:interpolationQuality:` method is calling `autorelease` on an object which has already previously been `autorelease`d. This can occur if you initialise the `UIImage` using a temporary constructor, like `+[UIImage imageWith...]`, earlier in the same method you call the scaling method from. The reason it works when you use `[anImage copy]` is because the behaviour of the `copy` constructor is such that the object returned to you has already had `retain` called on it (so it has a local retain count of 1 and zero `autorelease`s).

What happens at the end of the current run loop is: the autorelease pool which is currently in use is drained, and as a part of that two `release` messages will be sent to the `UIImage`. When the first one is sent, the application then runs off and calls `dealloc` on the image, because the `retainCount` has decreased to zero. When the second one is sent, the application throws an exception because a message is being sent to an object which was previously deallocated.

Try removing the `autorelease` message from the `scaleToFitWithin:interpolationQuality:` method. Even if your `resizedImage:interpolationQuality:` method IS returning a **new** object, you should only be calling `autorelease` in that method rather than the scaling method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the method `resizedImage:interpolationQuality:` itself returns an `autoreleased` object and you are again autoreleasing it in the *reutun* statement. Just remove the autorelease from the *return* statement,

```
return [[self normalize] resizedImage:newImageSize 
                 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
```

Then you don't have to *retain/release* or *copy* the returned object in `if (anImage) {...}` block.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It's hard to decide who gets the credit when the answers are close. I gave credit to David for the little extra explanation he provided, but you were right on as well.